# When using Facebook Graph API getting an error - Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have two applications -

- First - is a Facebook app.
- Second - is an app which sends a `Broadcast` to the first app.

For the ***First app*** I have asked the **Permissions** -

```
basic_info, email, user_photos, publish_actions
```

---

Now, the ***Second app*** triggers a `BroadcastReceiver` in the ***First app*** such that the first application is called and it tries to `Publish a feed`.

However, in the ***First app*** the call for `getOpenSession().getPermissions()` returns an empty List. Hence, I am getting the exception - (The reason might be something different too, I am not sure).

> `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

---

Since I have asked specifically for these **Permissions**, why does the `call for getPermissions()` return an empty array? Am I missing something? 
Apart from this what can be the **other** reasons for the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I wasn't passing the proper `Permissions` when making a `Request`. We set the `Permissions` like this -

```
request = new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity);
request.setDefaultAudience(...);
request.setLoginBehavior(...);
request.setPermissions(permission); // <-- This is where we need to specify the permissions.

session.openForPublish(request);
```

I do not know whether this is the ***proper solution***, but it seems to work for me.